# .NET regex match and replace

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My task is to verify a string with regex, than perform replacement if it match succeed or throw Exception if string don't match.

Obviously, I could check `Regex.IsMatch` and then call `Regex.Replace` or throw Exception:

```
var str = "89991112233";
var pattern = @"(?<prefix>8|\+?\d+)\s*(?<code>\d{3,3})\s*(?<phone>\d{7,7})";
var replace = "+7 ${code} ${phone}";

if (!Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern))
    throw new Exception();
else
    return Regex.Replace(str, pattern, replace);
```

but it requires two identical matching operations.

Can I perform regex check and get both if string was matching and the replacement in single call in .Net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may set a flag and set it to *true* if there was a match and then check if the flag was set to decide whether to throw the exception or return the string:

```cs
var str = "89991112233";
var pattern = @"^(?<prefix>8|\+?\d+)\s*(?<code>\d{3})\s*(?<phone>\d{7})\z";
var matched = false;
var result = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, m => {
    matched = !matched;
    return $"+7 ({m.Groups["code"].Value}) {m.Groups["phone"].Value}";
});
if (!matched)
    throw new Exception();
else
    return result;
```

Also, note that to match a whole string with the regex, you need anchors, I added `^` at the start and `\z` at the end.

Also, `{3,3}` is equal to `{3}` and `{7,7}` to `{7}`.

Comment: Thanks, for the advice, Wiktor! But, actually the case when replacement result equals original string is considered as a possible normal result and should not rise exception. Also, this method still requires additional checking after matching.

Comment: @obratim I have updated the answer, you need to check if there has been at least a single match inside a match evaluator. However, I doubt you can have a match for the input string with your current regex. My previous solution is available in [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64614275/1) (checking if new string is the same as the old string).